# How to divide div by 6?

Tags: html, css

Is there any native way to divide a div in 6 different parts as if it was a table with 6 equally sized columns (but I don't want it to be a table)? (native = no plugins)

```
    <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div> 
        <div></div> 
    </div>
```

I dont want them to have a width:16.66% because the browser resize never fills the whole width space. (the total percentage would end up being 99.96%)

Comment: Use floats and percentage widths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to avoid a framework such as bootstrap, rather than using just two decimal places, use a higher precision such as `16.66666666666667%` (as does bootstrap).

Answer (score 3):

Use twitter bootstrap grid system or similar grid systems.

Link for bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/

Ex. for google bootstrap:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">2</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">3</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">4</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">5</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">6</div>
</div>
```

**Native method** (I don't recomend this), making div's "table like":

```
<div style="display: table;">
    <div style="display: table-row;">
        <div style="display: table-cell;">1</div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;">2</div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;">3</div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;">4</div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;">5</div>
        <div style="display: table-cell;">6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think "*(native = no plugins)*" meant he or she wants to avoid using something like bootstrap?

Comment: I forgot to post the second part of the answer, this makes the div's table like.